# Android app crashes due to complex collection. Cannot evaluate the expression- failed to generate expression KTObject Literal exception

Tags: android, kotlin, collections, jvm, points

I am trying to cast object and it sometime crashes when object has an image url. But it works fine when I am using only string. How can I understand and resolve the issue?

```
val sourcedata : LinkedHashMap<String, MutableList<Any>> = somefunction()//this line is ok
var parsedData: LinkedHashMap<String, MutableList<String>> = 
  Gson().fromJson<LinkedHashMap<String, MutableList<String>>>(Gson().toJson(sourceData))!!
```

Also my inline function is below

```
inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String): T? = this.fromJson<T>(json, object : 
TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
```

Issue appears is -

> Cannot evaluate the expression : Backend (JVM) Internal Error
> Occurred : Failed to generate expression. KTObjectLiteral expression

Comment: can you share part of the `sourceData` that causes the issue? Both the working version (string) and nonworking one (imageUrl)

Comment: can you pls give one example of when you say - " crashes when object has an image url. But it works fine when I am using only string."

Comment: As others have mentioned, there doesn't seem to be enough information about what the `image url` is.
But since you are effectively trying to cast Any to String (inside MutableList inside LinkedHashMap), I think you could start by looking into if your URL extends String.

Also, you should probably add the Gson tag to this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to type-check, before attempting to type-cast.

For example (just debug to see which data-types need to be considered).

```
if(sourcedata is LinkedHashMap<String, MutableList<String>>) {

} else if(sourcedata is LinkedHashMap<String, MutableList<Uri>>) {

} else if(sourcedata is LinkedHashMap<String, MutableList<Any>>) {

}
```

Without having seen that part, you might not be adding the expected type to `sourcedata` already. When not being able to mix data-types, you could as well use two kinds of `MutableList<>`.

---

And I really wonder what you are trying to accomplish there:

```
Gson().fromJson< ... >(Gson().toJson(sourceData))
```